# Toggle Windows Explorer "Work Online" mode via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written several VBA macros that access intranet network locations. They work well when users are located on-site. However, when they are off-site and accessing the network via VPN, these network locations are not available unless they manually navigate to them via Windows Explorer and select the "work online" option at the top of the explorer window.

I can already verify whether they are connected via VPN programmatically.

What I need is to be able to perform the equivalent of activating "work online" mode via Excel VBA.

Any suggestions from the hive mind?

Didn't have any success via Google or existing SO posts.

Comment: I wish I could, but the scope of the macro recorder is within the Excel application context only, so toggling the Windows Explorer "Work Online" button would not be captured.

Comment: Is there a SendKey you could do that triggers that option?

Comment: I might have some ideas but I'm unfamiliar with the WE "Work online" option. Can you link to a screenshot of where this is located? There may be a command associated with Shell object or WinAPI that would do this for you.

Comment: Or, have you tried navigating to the files with the UNC path? THat may work where the named path doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be to trap the error when the folder cannot be accessed, display a message box to inform the user of the required option, and use `Shell` command to open the Windows Explorer:

```
Dim Foldername As String
Foldername = "\\UNCPATH\TO\NETWORK_DRIVE\"

Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Alternatively, you may be able to get this to work, although I could not, it was too long to post as a comment so I will include the procedure here:

```
Sub fnOfflineStatusVB()
    Dim objShell   As Object 'IShellDispatch5
    Dim objFolder As Object 'Folder3

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("\\UNCPATH\TO\NETWORK_DRIVE\")

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Dim nReturn As Integer

        nReturn = objFolder.OfflineStatus()
    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Found it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787858(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Found PowerShell commands that can be executed through CMD successfully. Roadblock that remains is integrating these into a batch file.

These CMD commands work when entered manually:

```DOS
powershell.exe -noexit "$oWMI=[wmiclass]""\\localhost\root\cimv2:win32_offlinefilescache"""
$oWMI.TransitionOnline("<path here>")
```

Where "Path here" in angle brackets is an UNC path on my network. However, executing them in a batch file has been unsuccessful thus far.

Here is the code:

```DOS
@ECHO ON

::Move to non UNC Path directory
cd /D "C:\"

powershell -NoExit -Command "& {'$oWMI=[wmiclass]''\\localhost\root\cimv2:win32_offlinefilescache';$oWMI.TransitionOnline('<Path here>')}"

:: Pause CMD window to give user confirmation that execution has occurred
PAUSE
```

If anyone has any suggestions on the issue, your advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Running PowerShell scripts directly are not permitted due to Group Policy set by IT, which is the reason for this round-about method.